# How to get a row vector and 2 column vectors on the same line

Tags: formatting, matrices

I have this small working example, and I am looking to get these 3 vectors onto the same line in latex. After reading other threads with similar issues the solutions to them are not applicable to me. They say us `\[` and `\]` but this doesn't work for mine. The other solution was to use `\begin{equation}` which once again doesnt work for mine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\[$N \, = \, (P,T,Pre,Post,M)$, 
 P &= \begin{pmatrix}
           Y_1 \\
           Y_2 \\
         \end{pmatrix},
 T &= \begin{pmatrix}
           Prey reproduction \\
           Predator-prey interaction \\
    Predator degradation \\
         \end{pmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After removing the syntax errors and adding `\text` for text I get all in the same equation line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[N \, = \, (P,T,\text{Pre},\text{Post},M),
 P = \begin{pmatrix}
           Y_1 \\
           Y_2 \\
         \end{pmatrix},
 T = \begin{pmatrix}
       \text{Prey reproduction} \\
       \text{Predator-prey interaction} \\
       \text{Predator degradation} \\
     \end{pmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]